# Prevent Automatic Hyperlinks being created for Text Area Fields

Tags: visualforce, custom-field

I have a custom object with a Long Text Area field to store a string that may be longer than 255 characters.

The contents of this string often includes text that looks like a hyperlink, but is not intended to be used as such.

E.g. somewhere in the value will appear a *domain*.com string:

> Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ground round exercitation **google.com** do laboris ham hock. Elit dolore aute consectetur, labore tenderloin anim eiusmod drumstick in.

Which Salesforce will render as:
[image: Salesforce Auto Hyperlink to Google.com in Bacon ipsum]

**How can I prevent Salesforce from automatically creating hyperlinks for these?**

It seems to happen anywhere the field is used on a page layout or directly bound to in Visualforce.

I did find in Visualforce I could wrap the field in the controller and bind to a string version rather than directly to the field. This prevented the hyperlinks from being created.

E.g.

```
public class BaconWrapper {
    public Bacon__c bacon {get;set;}

    // Bind to this.
    public string BaconIpsum {
        get {
            return bacon.BaconIpsum__c;
        }
    }

    public BaconWrapper(Bacon__c cBacon) {
        this.bacon = cBacon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you using outputtext or outputfield?

Comment: In Visualforce, among other things, I'm using `<apex:column value="{!b.bacon.BaconIpsum__c}" id="theValue">`. I guess I can deal with this field on a use-by-use basis to prevent the automatic hyperlinks. It doesn't directly address the standard page layouts.

Comment: Can't you add a CSS class on that column and set `text-decoration: none;` property?

Comment: I can handle the apex:column case by using the wrapper class to bind to a string rather than directly to the custom field. Ideally I'm looking for something I can do that will work everywhere for a string field that shouldn't contain hyperlinks. I suspect such a solution doesn't exist, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Pending any better answers, I'm going to conclude that there isn't a built in way to avoid the automatic hyperlinking of Text Area fields. You'll need to manually wrap them in a class and expose the value via a string property, bind to an outputtext control, use a formula field, etc...

I've raised the idea: [Make automatic hyper-linking on a Text Area field optional](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l3oqAAA)